# How to group similar rows in Excel, and total the values of each group?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with similar items in different rows. Each item has a unique value. For example:

[image]

I want to create a table that has one row for each of the similar rows (e.g., /ca/motion-type/abstract-4), and a sum of the values in the second column (e.g., 30).

Any idea how I can do this in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$9)/ISERR(FIND("?",A$2:A$9))/ISERR(FIND("/",A$2:A$9,17)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

In `E2` formula copied down :

```
=IF(D2="","",SUMIF(A:A,D2&"*",B:B))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution, based on a few assumptions:

1. All pages start with `/ca/motion-type/`
2. There's always at least one row containing the "base" url, e.g. `...abstract-4`
3. After removing `/ca/motion-type/`, any url not containing a `?` or `/` character should be considered a base url

Leave me a comment if any of these assumptions aren't correct and you're unable to adapt the solution. In that case I can try to adapt the solution for you.

#### Solution

[image: _]

Formulas used:

[image: _]

Formulas for easy copy/pasting:

D2: `=MID(A2;17;9999)`

E2: `=AND(ISERROR(FIND("?";D2));ISERROR(FIND("/";D2)))`

A14: `=FILTER(A2:A9;E2:E9)`

B14: `=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$9;$A$2:$A$9;"="&A14&"*")`